# Muted audio autoplay is not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, audio, iframe, autoplay

According to the Chrome Autoplay policy,

1. muted audio must be played automatically when it is set the attribute to autoplay true.
2. iframe allow="autoplay 'src' can play audio with sound

However, it was not working on my code.

The only way to allow to play audios automatically was user interactions and change the browser settings.

Could you check what it is wrong?

(I tested it in Chrome v 89.0.4389.90 64bit)

Test code #1

```
<body>
    <audio muted controls autoplay preload>
        <source src="https://freesound.org/data/previews/413/413749_5121236-lq.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
  </audio>
</body>
```

Teest code #2

```
<body>

<script>
var auto_audio = document.createElement('audio');

auto_audio.controls = true;
auto_audio.muted = true;
auto_audio.volume = 0;
auto_audio.autoplay = true;

var audio_src = document.createElement('source');
audio_src.src = 'https://freesound.org/data/previews/413/413749_5121236-lq.mp3';
audio_src.type = 'audio/mp3';

auto_audio.appendChild(audio_src);
document.body.appendChild(auto_audio);
</script>
</body>
```

Test code #3

```
<iframe allow="autoplay 'src'" src="https://freesound.org/data/previews/413/413749_5121236-lq.mp3" style="height:0;width:0;border:0;border:none;visibility:hidden;"></iframe>
```

Test code #4

```
<iframe allow="autoplay" src="https://freesound.org/data/previews/413/413749_5121236-lq.mp3" style="height:0;width:0;border:0;border:none;visibility:hidden;"></iframe>
```

Comment: What would be the point of playing a muted <audio>? Your code would work with a <video>

Comment: Did you find it? I think I have the exact same problem. I can't unmute my audio in chrome but on other browsers yes

Comment: Yes it doesn't work: https://video-dev.github.io/can-autoplay

Answer (score 2):

I was also not able to also have the autoplay for an iframe in chrome. I switch to `<video>` tag and it start working.

My Example:

```
<video autoplay loop muted src="path/to/image/" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></video>
```

I was able to get it autoplaying in every browser. Hope it helps